# Replace input value by variable and

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a sort of questionnaire/quiz in javascript for my website. The questionnaire is spread on 5 pages, each page has a question. I want to use the GET method so the URL of each page looks something like that:

(I must keep the GET method because I want to use for something else).

- First question: http://website.com/quiz/first?q=1
- Second question: http://website.com/quiz/second?q=133
- Third question: http://website.com/quiz/third?q=133
- Fourth question: http://website.com/quiz/fourth?q=1332
- Fifth question: http://website.com/quiz/fifth?q=13324

The user lands on the first page --> get a radio input form --> checks one --> gets redirected to the second page --> etc...

The ?q= is a variable containing the answers, for example ?q=133 means the user picked the following answers:

- In the first question, he checked the radio input of the value 1
- In the second question, he checked the radio input of the value 3
- In the third question, he checked the radio input of the value 3

(so 133 means the user check the 1 for the first question, 3 for the second, 3 for the third.)

---

I managed to make the variables work:

- answPre: gets the previous answer from the form GET (?q=1).
- answCurrent: gets the radio input checked from the current page.
- urlVal: an combination of the two (answPre+answCurrent)

so I'd like urlVal to be the value that gets transferred from a page to the other.
But I don't want to have both urlVal and the "q" value (name of checked radio) in the url.

What's the right thing to do?

- can I hide the "q" value from the URL?
- or can I "overwrite" the q value and put instead urlVal?

I'm lost and would appreciate any help, thanks for your help and your time!

```js
function displayRadioValue() {

 // var pageURL = window.location.href;
 var fakeURL="website.com/quiz/first?q=1"
  var answPre = fakeURL.substr(fakeURL.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);  //get the previous page's answer.

//get the current page's answer
    var ele = document.getElementsByName('q');
    for(j = 0; j < ele.length; j++) {
      if(ele[j].checked)
      var answCurrent= document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = ele[j].value;
    }

  var array = [answPre,answCurrent]; //combine answPre + answNew
  var urlVal = "";
  var i;
   for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     urlVal += array[i];
   }



document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = answPre;
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = urlVal;


//document.getElementById("fquiz").submit();// Form submission

}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h2>second.html</h2>

<b>answPre: </b><span id="demo1"></span><br>
<b>answCurrent: </b><span id="demo2"></span><br>
<b>urlVal: </b><span id="demo3"></span><br>
<!-- <b>final answNew: </b><span id="demo4"></span><br> -->

<hr>

<form id="fquiz" method="GET" action="third.html">

<p>Who are you going with?</p>
  <input type="radio" name="q" value="1" id="yes"
  onClick="javascript: displayRadioValue()">Solo<br>

  <input type="radio" name="q" value="2" id="no"
  onClick="javascript: displayRadioValue()">Couple<br>

  <input type="radio" name="q" value="3" id="no"
  onClick="javascript: displayRadioValue()">Family with kids<br>

  <input type="radio" name="q" value="4" id="no"
  onClick="javascript: displayRadioValue()">Group of friends<br>

<p>(then it takes you to third.html with hopefully this url: ../third.html?q=XX where XX is urlVal)
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not an answer, but note that you do not need to put `javascript:` before your function names in your `onclick` attributes. `javascript:` was only ever needed in `href` attributes on `a` tags.

Comment: I think the query string for your 2nd question is wrong in the example.

Comment: The question is confusing. You say "so I'd like urlVal to be the value that gets transferred from a page to the other. But I don't want to have both urlVal and the "q" value (name of checked radio) in the url." But i thought that's exactly what you want. Can you clarify, with examples?

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks I fixed it.

Comment: @wazz sorry I see how misleading it is now.

Comment: @wazz What I mean is that I'd like the url to be "website.com/quiz/first?q=133" where q is urlVal and NOT from the name of the checked input radio.

Comment: @wazz ?? I'd really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few changes to your code to modernize it a bit.

1. I moved the binding of the event handlers to the JavaScript from the HTML. Generally speaking I like to keep my HTML about the structure and the JavaScript about the behavior.
2. I added code to grab the step from the URL in addition to the previous answers.
3. I used [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to retrieve the selected radio button, using the [`:checked` pseudo-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).
4. I used [`join('')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on the array of answers to make it easier to read.
5. In the HTML, I used `<p>` elements for everything that needed to be in one line, rather than tacking a `<br>` at the end of each line. That's just a personal preference.
6. I wrapped the radio buttons and their text in `<label>` elements. This helps in accessibility and to give a larger target for people to click on (clicking on the entire label checks the radio, rather than just the radio itself).

I also changed the name of the URL parameter to `urlVal` rather than `q`, but I'm not sure I understood that part of your question. I'm not using the form submission process at all with this code, relying instead on changing the `location` directly...

Do note that running the code here on Stack Overflow won't redirect correctly, since of course there's nothing at example.com/quiz/second listening, and Stack Snippets are sandboxed anyway. You'll need to adjust the code for your specific use in any case.

```js
// Use JavaScript to attach event handlers to HTML elements.
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="q"]').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', displayRadioValue));

function displayRadioValue() {

  // var pageURL = window.location.href;
  var fakeURL = "example.com/quiz/first?q=1"
  var step = fakeURL.substring(fakeURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, fakeURL.indexOf('?'));
  var answPre = fakeURL.substr(fakeURL.lastIndexOf('=') + 1); //get the previous page's answer.

  //get the current page's answer
  // The :checked pseudo-class makes it easier to find the checked radio button
  var el = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]:checked');
  var answCurrent = document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = el.value;
  var array = [answPre, answCurrent]; //combine answPre + answNew
  // The join method is easier to use than looping.
  var urlVal = array.join('');

  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = answPre;
  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = urlVal;
  
  switch (step) {
    case 'first': step = 'second'; break;
    case 'second': step = 'third'; break;
    case 'third': step = 'final'; break;
    default: return;
  }
  
  location.href = `example.com/quix/${step}?urlVal=${urlVal}`;
}
```

```css
.form-group { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<h2>second.html</h2>

<!-- <br> is a presentational element; better just to split up lines with paragraphs -->
<p class="form-group"><b>answPre: </b><span id="demo1"></span></p>
<p class="form-group"><b>answCurrent: </b><span id="demo2"></span></p>
<p class="form-group"><b>urlVal: </b><span id="demo3"></span></p>
<!-- <p class="form-group"><b>final answNew: </b><span id="demo4"></span></p> -->

<hr>

<form id="fquiz" method="GET" action="third.html">

  <p>Who are you going with?</p>
<!-- <br> is a presentational element; better just to split up lines with paragraphs -->
<!-- Always use <label> elements to label form fields -->
<!-- IDs must be unique to a document. They did not appear relevant here. -->
  <p class="form-group"><label><input type="radio" name="q" value="1">Solo</label></p>
  <p class="form-group"><label><input type="radio" name="q" value="2">Couple</label></p>
  <p class="form-group"><label><input type="radio" name="q" value="3">Family with kids</label></p>
  <p class="form-group"><label><input type="radio" name="q" value="4">Group of friends</label></p>
  <p>(then it takes you to third.html with hopefully this url: ../third.html?q=XX where XX is urlVal)</p>
</form>
```

Comment: This is so clean, thank you so much for your time!!
Your notes are valuable and make me realize how much I have to learn.
Thanks again!!